# Divs moving out of parent div, using flexbox

Tags: html, css

I got this flex-box problem,
    i got 2 divs contained in 1 div, each one of the is a flexbox too, the Divs pop out of the parent div,
    i want them to never move out the parent divs dimensions,
    the divs go over the table below them at the moment,
    how do i accomplish this?
    Another Question:
 I would like to ask is, in the div named container i got a table,
    i want that table to be dead center of the div, and of course never collide with the footer or header

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
  height: 20%;
}

.header h1 {
  width: 100%;
}

.secondHeader {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.levels {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  background: green;
  margin: 5px;
}

.main-Game-Body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  height: 72%;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 4px;
}

.container {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.footer {
  height: 8%;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Welcome To Minesweeper</h1>
    <div class="secondHeader">
      <button class="hints" onclick="activateHintMode()">
                You Have: <span></span> Hints Left
              </button>
      <button class="safe" onclick="safeClick()">
                You Have: <span></span> safe clicks Left
              </button>
      <button class="lives">You Have: <span></span> Lives Left</button>
      <button class="backUp" onclick="stepBack()">stepBack</button>
    </div>
    <div class="levels">
      <button class="manual" onclick="manualMode()">
                Manual Mode
              </button>
      <button class="level" onclick="easyMode()">Easy Mode</button>
      <button class="level" onclick="hardMode()">Hard Mode</button>
      <button class="level" onclick="expertMode()">EXPERT</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main-Game-Body">
    <!-- <button class="icon" onclick="restartLevel()"></button> -->
    <div class="container"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="timer" onclick="timer()">
      Your Score: <span class="stopwatch"></span> Best Score At Difficulty
      <span class="difficulty"></span> is: <span class="results"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When does this moves out? What is the testing scenario?

Comment: the second div(levels), its like its not part of the header div, if i add a margin to it, it still sticks to the table below it, it gives me the margin from the top but not the bottom,

also when i zoom in to the page,however that's not important at the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the issue with `levels` div. You have given static height to each div that's why the content is trying to fit in that height. When you try to increase the margin the element treis to reside inside the container height resulting in moving the items above `levels` div outside the container.

**Solution:** Remove static height for `header`, `main-Game-Body` and `footer`, use `flex-grow: 1` for `main-Game-Body` this will help fitting the content in remaining height.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  /* height: 20%; */
}

.header h1{
  width: 100%;
}
.secondHeader {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  
}

.levels {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  background: green;
  margin: 5px;

}

.main-Game-Body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  /* height: 72%; : Do not give height, use flex grow*/
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 4px;
}

.container {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.footer {
  /* height: 8%; */
  margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="header">
        <h1>Welcome To Minesweeper</h1>
        <div class="secondHeader">
        <button class="hints" onclick="activateHintMode()">
            You Have: <span></span> Hints Left
        </button>
        <button class="safe" onclick="safeClick()">
            You Have: <span></span> safe clicks Left
        </button>
        <button class="lives">You Have: <span></span> Lives Left</button>
        <button class="backUp" onclick="stepBack()">stepBack</button>
        </div>
        <div class="levels">
        <button class="manual" onclick="manualMode()">
            Manual Mode
        </button>
        <button class="level" onclick="easyMode()">Easy Mode</button>
        <button class="level" onclick="hardMode()">Hard Mode</button>
        <button class="level" onclick="expertMode()">EXPERT</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-Game-Body">
        <!-- <button class="icon" onclick="restartLevel()"></button> -->
        <div class="container"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="timer" onclick="timer()">
        Your Score: <span class="stopwatch"></span> Best Score At Difficulty
        <span class="difficulty"></span> is: <span class="results"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```